# Fetching from keyserver fails with GnuPG 2

Tags: gnupg

How do I receive keys from keyservers, with GnuPG 2?

The GnuPG FAQ document [recommends I use `pool.sks-keyservers.net` for the keyserver](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/gnupg-faq.html#new_user_default_keyserver). That has worked for a long time in GnuPG 1, but in GnuPG 2:

```
$ gpg2 --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys DECAFBAD
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Invalid argument
```

What does “Invalid argument” mean? Which argument, and what validation failed?

Version information:

```
$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
libgcrypt 1.7.3-beta
```

How do I use `gpg2` to receive a key from the keyserver network?

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `--keyserver name` is deprecated in GnuPG 2. That's why it says:
 `keyserver receive failed: Invalid argument`, because the argument is invalid, as in, deprecated.

Use `--keyserver` in `dirmngr.conf` instead.

---

**TIPS:**

You can use the following option in `gpg2`:

```
show-keyserver-urls
```

This will show any preferred keyserver URL in the `--list-sigs` or `--check-sigs` listings.

To list directories to search for and keyserver helpers, use:

```
--exec-path string
```

Comment: Deprecated does not mean invalid, but "will be removed in some future release, don't rely on it any more if you want to update at some time". Using it is totally fine, although I wouldn't recommend doing so when writing software that interfaces GnuPG.

Answer (score 0):

While the `--keyserver` option is indeed deprecated for the most recent versions of GnuPG, you can still use it. The issue you're having is another one: you have to specify the protocol you want to use.

From `man gpg`:

```
--keyserver name

      This option is deprecated - please use the --keyserver in ‘dirmngr.conf’
      instead.

      Use name as your keyserver. This is the server that --recv-keys,
      --send-keys, and --search-keys will communicate with to receive keys from,
      send keys to,  and  search  for keys  on. The format of the name is a URI:
      `scheme:[//]keyservername[:port]' The scheme is the type of keyserver:
      "hkp" for the HTTP (or compatible) keyservers, "ldap" for LDAP keyservers,
      or "mailto" for the Graff email keyserver.
```

Especially observe that `scheme:` is *not* optional.

Use `gpg2 --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys DECAFBAD` instead to provide an ad-hoc change of the keyserver.